# Is there a way to load into a specific column in excel/csv without dataframe(Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a list of items into a specific column of the csv.

I tried to look for a lot of answer and tutorial online and they only showed how to do it with dataframe.
I am wondering is there a way where I can just look for the Column name and load into that column since some of the excel sheet they have different column names?

```
data = pd.read_excel(filenames)
        data.loc['Price']=pricelist
        data.to_csv(filenames,index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

This is my current code, it doesnt work and return an error of "cannot set a row with mismatched columns"

| Items | Stock | Price(Search by this column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 5 | trying to load into this column |
| Item 2 | 76 | trying to load into this column |

Comment: *they have different column names* - how they are differ? is there some pattern?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest There are no pattern, some excel sheet may have more columns  according to items and some can have less column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFrame.loc` is used to access rows and columns.
Your line `data.loc['Price']=pricelist` attempts to set the *row* with the name "Price", not the column.

Have you instead tried `data['Price']=pricelist`?

Comment: Hi! I just did, the program runs without any issue, however the excel file after is corrupted, is there a fix for it?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work, puted the wrong extention LOL